# How to find dlls that are being using?

Tags: c#, .net, dll

I lack the concept of dll reference.
Please let me know if there's anything I think is wrong.

Not [**Status referencing dll**], but [**Status when dll is using**].
I'll give you a clear example because the title alone is ambiguous to express what I'm trying to say.

The Main Program reference to A.dll and B.dll.
The following is the source in the dlls.

```
//A.dll
namespace A {
    public static void Work10sec() {
        //Working for 10 seconds.
    }
}
//B.dll
namespace B {
    public static void Work5sec() {
        //Working for 5 seconds.
    }
}
```

And I call A.Work10sec() and B.Work5sec() in the main program.

```
namespace Main {
    static class Program {
        [STAThread]
        static void Main() {
            A.Work10sec();
            B.Work5sec();
        }
    }
}
```

I think after starting the program, A.dll is in use for 0-10 seconds. and B.dll is in use for 10-15 seconds.
If so, how does the Main Program know that A.dll is in use in 0-10 seconds?
and How do I know that A.dll is not used in 10-15 seconds in the Main Program?

---

There is a misunderstanding, so I edited the question.
Thread.Sleep() ==> //Working other

---

Result: The dll being referred to soon proved to be the dll being used.

```
//A.dll
namespace A {
    public static bool used = false;
    public static void Work10sec() {
        used = true;
        //Working for 10 seconds.
        used = false;
    }
}
```

Please let me know if there is a better way.

Comment: That's not at all how it works.  Books have been written about it, Jeffrey Richter never disappoints.

Comment: I agree with Hans and I've read Jeffrey Richters books and you should check them out. Since you've marked the Program.cs with a Single Thread Apartment the call to Thread.Sleep() will not be called asynchronously. The DLLs get loaded into memory and they also get cached so next time you run it will be quicker. DLLs aren't like Managed Reference Objects that are subject to Garbage Collection, nor Values types on the Thread Stack. DLLs are a different concept.

Comment: Thread.Sleep() is a method for easy understanding of 10 seconds.   
It's actually a separate action that runs for 10 seconds.

Comment: "how does the Main Program know that A.dll is in use in 0-10 seconds?" It doesn't.